# Remove droppable functionality on success using jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have the following code which allows you to drag and drop elements on a page and on successful drop it runs a method called saveRatings passing the ids of the elements.

```
            $('.draggable').draggable({
                revert: true
            });


            $('.droppable').droppable({
                drop: function( event, ui ) {
                    draggedID = ui.draggable.attr("id");
                    droppedID = $(this).attr("id");
                    Global.showLoader('Saving...');
                    quiz1.saveRatings(draggedID, droppedID);
                }
            });
```

The plan is that once a successful drop has taken place it will then remove the dragged item and remove the droppable class from the dropped element to prevent other elements from also being dropped there:

```
saveRatings: function ( choiceId, ratingId ) {

                // Hide the dragged choice
                $('div#' + choiceId).hide();

                // Remove droppable behaviour
                $('div#' + ratingId).removeClass('ui-droppable');
                $('div#' + ratingId).removeClass('droppable');
                $('div#' + ratingId).addClass('done');

}
```

The removal part works fine as does the removing of the classes BUT the element still allows others to be dropped on it... even though I have removed the droppable and ui-droppable classes from the element...

Any ideas why this isn't working? I can't show a fiddle as the full-code base is rather large (but doesn't directly effect this) But the examples above should explain the issue enough for a solution hopefully.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use `disable`:

```
$('#' + ratingId).droppable('disable')
```

Also, you don't need to specify `'div#'` when selecting by ID, as ID's are unique.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NXDhE/) (using destroy)

Comment: Or $('div#' + ratingId).droppable( "destroy" ) if he wants to completley get rid of the droppable.

Comment: @Cameron: because jQuery UI binds listeners to the elements themselves, and changing some properties of those elements won't automatically unbind the listeners.

Comment: @victorvartan: yeah, if we know that the droppable is at no point going to be re-enabled, I suppose destroying it is preferable performance-wise.

Comment: This solution doesn't actually disable the droppable correctly, it breaks the droppable so that you can't re-enable it.  See my answer  if you need to keep the functionality and re-enable it.

Answer (score 9):

You can use:

```
$('#' + ratingId).droppable('destroy')
```

This will permanently remove the droppable behavior from  the element.  If you want to reinitialize it, you just have to make the element droppable again using the same initialization code as when you first initialized it.

For more information, see the documentation: http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#method-destroy

Answer (score 3):

The solution in the accepted answer breaks the droppaple, which means it only appears to have disabled it. But if you do it this way, you cannot enable it again later. According to the [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.8/Droppable#options) , the correct way to do this without breaking the element is:

```
//Get or set the disabled option, after init.
//getter
var disabled = $( ".selector" ).droppable( "option", "disabled" );
//setter
$( ".selector" ).droppable( "option", "disabled", true );
```

Comment: The above should work with enable being the converse http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#method-disable